# How do I create an html link in a semantic-ui menu

Tags: hyperlink, menu, semantic-ui

I am new to semantic-ui and I am having trouble creating an html link for a menu item, below is my test code:

```
 <div class="ui blue borderless main menu">
<a href="#" class="blue item" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">
  Home
</a>
<a href="#" class="ui floated dropdown item" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">
  Products
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <a class="item" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
      <a class="item" href="http://www.zdnet.com">Zdnet</a>
    </div>
</a>
```

What I get displayed is:
Home Products> Google Zdnet

What I want is Google and Zdnet to be displayed as items of Products:

Home |Products|
            |Google   |
           |Zdnet    |

Can anybody tell me what I need to do to my code to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you included `jQuery` and `semantic.min.js` libraries in `<head>` section (jQuery first!).

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="ui blue borderless main menu">
  <a href="#" class="blue item" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">Home</a>
  <div  class="ui dropdown item" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">
  Products
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <a class="item" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
      <a class="item" href="http://www.zdnet.com">Zdnet</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
  $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your suggested changes and I still cannot display the items in the drop down menu, they are still displayed on the main menu.

Comment: Thanks it now works me. It seems that putting dropdown script outside the header is key as well as the jquery.